# How to run the GParted Live CD image?

Tags: virtualbox, gparted, virtualization, iso, live-cd

I downloaded the `gparted-live-0.26.0-2-i686.iso` from the [Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php/livecd.php) page and added to my VM:

[image]

A double click on the CD icon on the Desktop only opens the image folder. The option "Open With Run Software" is not available:

[image]

How to start GParted from its Live CD image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused by multiple images added to the VM. After I removed all the images excepting the GParted ISO, it started working.

<sub>After that I got another little problem: The GParted Live CD failed to continue after selecting the basic options (mode, language etc.). The [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217199/43477) was to enable the "EFI" option.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The GParted Live .iso file is a bootable CD image.

Did you connect the .iso image to the Optical Drive in the VM and then start the VM?

Answer (score 2):

In VirtualBox goto System and make sure the Boot Order starts with Optical. For me default was to boot from hard disk